# Take one spreadsheet and fill in the roles for the user in columns

Tags: excel

So basically I'm trying to take a csv/excel file from PeopleSoft and reformat it to another sheet.

Basically PeopleSoft will list the username,role so if there's multiple roles it would be like this:

user1,role
user1,role2
user1,role3
user1,role4

I want to be able to put this into a new spreadsheet with defined columns of those roles and only have the username appear once.

Username   | Role | Role2 | Role3 | Role4
User 1     |   X  |   X   |   X   |   X
User 2     |  X   |       |   X   |   X

I've tried various ways of searching for it, but I haven't stumbled upon a method that would work in this case. I'm not really a programmer but more in creating quarterly reports and instead of making sure that the role is checked for the user, I could just have it generated and move on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider using a formula like this one?

```
=OFFSET($A2,0,MAX((COLUMN()-COLUMN($J2))*2-1,0))
```

Here A2 holds "User 1", with "role|user1|role2|user1|role3 |user1|role4" following in B2:H2. The formula must be written to J2 and copied from there to J2:N[end]. If it's pasted to another cell that cell's address must appear in the formula.

The formula will copy A2:B2 and every other cell after that, meaning D2, F2 and H2. So, J2:N2 will show "Username | Role | Role2 | Role3 | Role4". More column pairs could be added.

The formula will return 0 (zero) for blank cells. Rather than combating that with IFs in the formula I suggest to suppress display of zeros in the cell format.